# Windows Service Error: Installog access is Denied

Tags: .net, windows-services, installation

I get following error while installing my Windows service through Command prompt

`Access to the path 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\InstallUtil.In
stallLog' is denied.`

I am using following command:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727>installutil.exe "C:\Hive-WindowsService\HiveBatchProcess\HiveBatchProcess\bin\Debug\HiveBatchProcess.exe" -i
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: Check permissions on installutil.installlog and attributes:  commands are -- cacls C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\InstallUtil.InstallLog -- and -- attrib C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\InstallUtil.InstallLog -- make sure file is not read-only and ACL'd correctly.

Comment: Hey Seva Titov, I am new into this windows service so can you please give information on where I should execute this? VS2008 Command Prompt or Windows Command Prompt?

Comment: Either of these would work. Just make sure you run the command prompt elevated (right click -> run as administrator).

Comment: Thanks got it working. I was not opening Command Prompt as Administrator and hence it was not giving me permissions to install the service. :) Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

do you have administrator rights ? Try to run the service setup by launching the command prompt as administartor.

Comment: I am running it as Administrator. But still the error doesnt get solved. What could be wrong?

Comment: Thanks got it working. Just right clicked the VS2008 Command Prompt and Clicked **Run as Administrator**. Thanks Felice Pollano. :)

Comment: Running `installutil.exe` does not absolutely require administrator permissions. It just hooks into the install code in the executable being installed - so the permissions required depend on that executable.

The error message specified in the question is just about permissions to create the log file, which _does not_ require running as administrator. See my answer below...

Comment: I had to run Powershell as an Administrator and then installed the service.

Answer (score 2):

Try running from a different directory (eg %TEMP%)- it just needs access to write the log file to the current directory, and by default non-administrators can't write to {{c:\Windows}} subdirectories.

eg:

```
cd %TEMP%
"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\installutil.exe" "C:\Hive-WindowsService\HiveBatchProcess\HiveBatchProcess\bin\Debug\HiveBatchProcess.exe" -i
```

Depending on what the install logic in HiveBatchProcess.exe does, you may or may not need additional permissions (eg registry access, write access to other directories, etc).  But running `installutil.exe` does not strictly require administrator permissions.

Answer (score 1):

cd "%temp%" then
"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\installutil.exe" "\ourServiceexe.exe"

i changed the service password to admin password of the server