# Cannot Open <service-name> Service On Computer. Access Is Denied Even When Granted Full Access

Tags: c#, windows-7, windows-services, access-denied, autostart

I am starting a windows service i developed (automatic). I have tried out all the options in 48 hours with no luck sadly. Install log says the following:

```
An exception occurred in the OnAfterInstall event handler of System.ServiceProcess.ServiceInstaller.
System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot open AutoStart service on computer '.'.
The inner exception System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception was thrown with the following error message: Access is denied.
```

"Access is denied". According to what i found on internet, I'm logged in as an administrator. I have added permissions (Full control - Account: LocalService) in debug folder and running the service as an administrator. I have also added permissions to Windows Registery "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHIENE->SYSTEM->CurrentControlSet->services->wcncsvc" of both LocalService Account and rebooted the system but still it says in the installlog "Access is denied"!
What access is it talking about now? I'm using windows7 32bit.
There's nothing in the onstart and onstop methods.

Comment: How are you installing this service program? More information might be helpful. (There are several different ways of installing a Windows service program. Personally I recommend using the WiX installer, but that is a major investment in learning how to use WiX.)

Comment: I'm installing it through ManagedInstallerClass, i have the following in the main() function:
ManagedInstallerClass.InstallHelper(new string[]{ Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location }); 

And on service AfterInstall event, i'm starting it through ServiceController.start. It throws an exception while starting.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not at all familiar with ManagedInstallerClass, didn't know it existed. Could the "Cannot open AutoStart service on computer '.'" part of the exception be significant? I.e., are you failing to specify the name of your own computer? Or does "." imply your own computer?

Comment: Another possibility is for you to try using the Installutil program directly from a command window, just to try to get something working, then switch back to ManagedInstallerClass if/when you find the problem. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/50614e95%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: I think it '.' applies to local domain on which the user's being logged in. I have also tried Environment.MachineName which gives the exact domain/computer but it fails there too:(

Comment: Have you tried Googling "Installutil "access is denied""? Lots of hits. For example this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5459643/windows-service-error-installog-access-is-denied He suggests running Visual Studio elevated to Administrator.

Comment: With installutil, it does the same. Installs it correctly but when i try to start it through services.msc, it gives the same message. Cannot start service on local computer.

Comment: I have already tried thousands of solutions but none working:( Yes, I'm logged in as administrator, running everything as administrator.

Comment: OK, I'm afraid I can't help, good luck.